# NativeSearchQuery is deprecated what is the equivalent beyond 5.0

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

What is the equivalent of org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQuery for support beyond 5.0.

Migrated the following snippet from

```
    NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilterBuilder().withIncludes().build())
            .withQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery(Configuration.CONFIGURATION_TYPE, field))
            .withSorts(new FieldSortBuilder(Configuration.NAME).order(SortOrder.ASC)).withPageable(pageable)
            .build();
```

to the following query, but it fails

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.NativeQuery;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.NativeQueryBuilder;


    NativeQuery query = new NativeQueryBuilder()
            .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilterBuilder().withIncludes().build())
            .withQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery(Configuration.CONFIGURATION_TYPE, field))
            .withSorts(new FieldSortBuilder(Configuration.NAME).order(SortOrder.ASC)).withPageable(pageable)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

use Native Query,

```
    package com.lazyaudio;

    import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.NativeQuery;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.QueryBuilders;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.FetchSourceFilterBuilder;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Pageable pageable = null;
            NativeQuery query = NativeQuery.builder()
                    .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilterBuilder().withIncludes().build())
                    .withQuery(QueryBuilders.termQueryAsQuery("fieldName", ""))
                    .withSort(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "fieldName"))
                    .withPageable(pageable)
                    .build();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, thank you. For my part, I also want to perform a groupBy on 'brand' by aggregation.

The JSON query I'm trying to formulate with NativeQuery looks like this:

```
{
     "size": 0,
     "aggs": {
         "distinct_brand": {
             "terms": {
                 "field": "brand",
                 "size": 10000,
                 "order": {
                 "_key": "asc"
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

And my code is currently like this:

```
 Query query = NativeQuery.builder()
         .withQuery(q -> q
                 .matchAll(my -> my))
         .withSort(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "brand")).build();
```

How can I add the aggregation?