# IllegalArgumentException: unhandled Query implementation org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.erhlc.NativeSearchQuery

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm encountering an issue with the Spring Data Elasticsearch library when using JDK 17 and Spring Boot version 3.1. The problem arises when I try to execute a search operation using NativeSearchQueryBuilder and NativeSearchQuery. The search operation works as expected with this configuration.

However, when I upgraded to JDK 17 and Spring Boot version 3.1, the same search operation throws an IllegalArgumentException with the message "unhandled Query implementation org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.erhlc.NativeSearchQuery."

I have verified that the Elasticsearch dependencies are compatible with Spring Boot 3.1, and the Elasticsearch server is running correctly. It appears that the issue is related to the Spring Data Elasticsearch library or its compatibility with the new versions.

Here are the relevant details of my setup:

JDK version: JDK 17
Spring Boot version: 3.1
Spring Data Elasticsearch version: [Specify the version you are using]
Elasticsearch server version: [Specify the version you are using]
I have already tried the following steps without success:

Checked the Elasticsearch configuration for correctness
Verified the compatibility of dependencies
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any insights on how to resolve it? Any suggestions, guidance, or workarounds would be highly appreciated.

I have written all my logic of aggregation, date-histogram and all using executing with help of NativeSearchQueryBuilder

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` class, and the `NativeSearchQuery` instances produced by it were deprecated in Spring Data Elasticsearch 5.0.
I assume your upgrade for Spring Boot 3.1 has also changed the spring data dependency version as well, perhaps to latest.

Instead you should replace with `NativeQuery.builder()` following the example from this previous SO answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76007192/362792

The official docs for this (I think) are below, see "Package Changes" section.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/5.1.2/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.4-5.0.breaking-changes-packages