How to do wildcardquery search for elasticsearch in springboot 3 using java 8

Need solution for wildcard search in elasticsearch using java 8 and spring boot 3.


Im using java 17 version.
Springboot version 3.2.4
Elasticsearch 8.13

Using NativesearchQueryBuilder was not supported in above springboot 3.

Your title says Java 8, your body says Java 17. Which is it?

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76007192/1303158

Sorry for the confusion..Java 17 only..but im asking for java 8 or above

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes Bernie it was working. Thanks a lot
